# How can I train the semantic role labeling model in AllenNLP?

Tags: python, nlp, allennlp

How can I train the [semantic role labeling model in AllenNLP](https://demo.allennlp.org/semantic-role-labeling/NjU2MjA3)?

I am aware of the [`allennlp.training.trainer`](https://allenai.github.io/allennlp-docs/api/allennlp.training.trainer.html) function but I don't know how to use it to train the semantic role labeling model.

Let's assume that the training samples are BIO tagged, e.g.:

```
Remove B_O
the B_ARG1
fish I_ARG1
in B_LOC
the I_LOC 
background I_LOC
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look at the [tutorial](https://allennlp.org/tutorials). These are the steps you need to do to train the allennlp model:

- Create a `.jsonnet` experiment. In this case if you want to use the existing SRL model, take a look at the `training_config` directory in the allennlp repository.
- Run `allennlp train <path to .jsonnet> -s <path to output directory>`